.NET 8 isolated Azure function not running anymore
I saw this morning that an Azure function was not running anymore, while I didn't change anything to the code/configuration. I tried to disable and enable the function, but since I disabled it, it does not appear anymore on my Azure Function dashboard.
This is what I get in the logs:

And sometimes I have this different error message:

No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I did update the dependencies to be the following a week ago:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>

In my test environment, with the same configs, it works fine. I double-checked the configs and I have the right configuration for isolated workers.
My Azure function is a TimerTrigger:
[Function(nameof(ReservationConfirmation))]
public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
    // ...
}

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            var toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

I have no idea what am I missing and how to fix that.

The issue was coming from the deployment mode I use, which is an issue introduced by the upload artifact GHA
In my case, it had nothing to do with code/AF configuration. If you encouter this issue, also check your deployment.
